# Can an immutable type change its internal state?

Tags: c#, immutability

The question is simple. Can a type that can change its internal state without it being observable from the outside be considered *immutable*?

Simplified example:

```
public struct Matrix
{
    bool determinantEvaluated;
    double determinant;

    public double Determinant 
    {
         get //asume thread-safe correctness in implementation of the getter
         {
             if (!determinantEvaluated)
             {
                  determinant = getDeterminant(this);
                  determinantEvaluated = true;
             }

             return determinant;    
         }
    }
}
```

*UPDATE*: Clarified the thread-safeness issue, as it was causing distraction.

Comment: `Matrix` is not thread-safe (one of expected properties from immutables), so it's not immutable.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: That would suggest that Java Strings aren't immutable, contrary to just about every resource on the planet :) Also note the third sentence in Wikipedia: "In some cases, an object is considered immutable even if some internally used attributes change but the object's state appears to be unchanging from an external point of view."

Comment: @Sinatr Hence the simplified example. Making it thread-safe would not be that complicated. Also, claiming that its not thread-safe, is kind of dubious. You would pay the price of evaluating the determinant multiple times but the value would not change.

Comment: Though I don't think that "the type isn't thread safe" also must mean "therefore it cannot be immutable". Those are two different things.

Comment: With instruction and write reordering the Matrix type is not thread-safe. Without memory barriers or volatile reads/writes, the evaluated field could be set to true before the determinant, making other threads observe inconsistent values.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Point taken, you are right. Still that wasn't the intention of the question. That is an implementation detail that can be taken care of.  Assuming the type is thread-safe, is it immutable?

Comment: No, thread-safety and immutability are two different things. You can guarantee both, but guaranteeing one does not implicitly guarantee the other.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I was not asking about the general case, I'm talking about the specific `Matrix` implementation. If it is not thread-safe then two observers can see two different states of the object which would automaticlaly make the type not immutable (one observer could be seeing determinant 0 and another -10 for instance). However if its thread-safe there is not way to externally observe the internal state change. Would it then mean the type is immutable? And it begs the question: *thread-safeness* does not imply *immutablitiy*, but does *immutability* require  *thread-safeness*?

Comment: Do we continue the discussion? :) The immutability has another side, that is difficult to relate to C#, but it's possible to relate to C/C++. The question is: can a compiler locate data that marked as read-only in the real read-only memory (ROM, not RAM).

Comment: This blog article might be relevant: [Eric Lippert - Immutability in C# Part One: Kinds of Immutability](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/11/13/immutability-in-c-part-one-kinds-of-immutability.aspx)

Comment: Immutability is just an abstraction. Underneath, the hardware is mutating all the things.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, immutable *can change* its state, providing that the changes are 
*unseen* for other components of the software (usually caches). Quite
like quantum physics: an event should have an observer to be an event.

In your case a possible implementation is something like that:

```
  public class Matrix {
    ...
    private Lazy<Double> m_Determinant = new Lazy<Double>(() => {
      return ... //TODO: Put actual implementation here
    });

    public Double Determinant {
      get {
        return m_Determinant.Value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Note, that `Lazy<Double> m_Determinant` *has* a changing state

```
m_Determinant.IsValueCreated
```

which is, however, *unobservable*.

Answer (score 34):

It depends.

If you are documenting for authors of client code or reasoning as an author of client code, then you are concerned with the interface of the component (that is, its externally observable state and behavior) and not with its implementation details (like the internal representation).

In this sense, a type is immutable even if it caches state, even if it initializes lazily, etc - as long as these mutations aren't observable externally. In other words, a type is immutable if it behaves as immutable when used through its public interface (or its other intended use cases, if any).

Of course, this can be tricky to get right (with mutable internal state, you may need to concern yourself with thread safety, [serialization/marshaling behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31723199/1892179), etc). But assuming you do get it right (to the extent you need, at least) there's no reason *not* to consider such a type immutable.

Obviously, from the point of view of a compiler or an optimizer, such a type is typically not considered immutable (unless the compiler is sufficiently intelligent or has some "help" like hints or prior knowledge of some types) and any optimizations that were intended for immutable types may not be applicable, if this is the case.

Comment: Let's say I initialize the determinant the first time, it takes 200ms. then the second time I access it, it takes 2ms. The same value is return twice, with different performance. Can we still say that both calls have the same behaviour if one is O(n) and the other O(1)? Is the method still immutable? Is the Immutable definition take performance as a criteria?

Comment: @CyrilGandon (1) If the time or the algorithmic complexity of a method's implementation aren't documented explicitly, then it would be foolish for client code to depend on it for correctness. (2) I've never heard of any particular degree of performance as a *requirement* to call a type immutable. And it makes sense, since performance is partly a matter of the language implementation. For instance, could a type ever be considered "immutable" under a sufficiently optimizing compiler/runtime but "mutable" under another compiler/runtime, if the language and the source code were exactly the same?

Comment: @CyrilGandon In the same vein, if you are given an unrelated method that's documented as pure (reads only from the state you pass to it and causes no external side effects) and it finishes normally the first time you call it, but happens to cause a full GC the second time you call it (causing finalizers to run), would you say it behaved differently? Would you say that it's not pure? I think you wouldn't, because we *expect* GC to be non-deterministic (and kick in at any moment), the same way we *expect* any kind of performance to be technically non-deterministic in any non real time system.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to [quote Clojure author Rich Hickey here](http://clojure.org/transients):

> If a tree falls in the woods, does it make a sound?
>
> If a pure function mutates some local data in order to produce an immutable return value, is that ok?

It is perfectly reasonable to mutate objects that are expose APIs which are immutable to the outside for performance reasons. The important thing about immutable object is their immutability to the outside. Everything that is encapsulated within them is fair game.

In a way in garbage collected languages like C# all objects have some state because of the GC. As a consumer that should not usually concern you.

Answer (score 5):

I'll stick my neck out...

No, an immutable object cannot change its internal state in C# because observing its memory is an option and thus you can observe the uninitialised state. Proof:

```
public struct Matrix
{
    private bool determinantEvaluated;
    private double determinant;

    public double Determinant
    {
        get
        {
            if (!determinantEvaluated)
            {
                determinant = 1.0;
                determinantEvaluated = true;
            }

            return determinant;
        }
    }
}
```

then...

```
public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var unobserved = new Matrix();
        var observed = new Matrix();

        Console.WriteLine(observed.Determinant);

        IntPtr unobservedPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Matrix)));
        IntPtr observedPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Matrix)));

        byte[] unobservedMemory = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Matrix))];
        byte[] observedMemory = new byte[Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Matrix))];

        Marshal.StructureToPtr(unobserved, unobservedPtr, false);
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(observed, observedPtr, false);



        Marshal.Copy(unobservedPtr, unobservedMemory, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Matrix)));
        Marshal.Copy(observedPtr, observedMemory, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (Matrix)));

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unobservedPtr);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(observedPtr);

        for (int i = 0; i < unobservedMemory.Length; i++)
        {
            if (unobservedMemory[i] != observedMemory[i])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not the same");
                return;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The same");
    }
}
```

Comment: First off, this test is wrong because you are freeing memory and then copying it, which causes you to read garbage (you can verify this in the debugger). Second, if you fix the previous issue, the result is indeed a memory layout that's not identical (one instance has a 0 where the other has a 1). But the question wasn't about in-memory representations of the instances, it was about immutability of the instances themselves. To make this test meaningful, you'd need to compare instances of the type itself, so you'd need to at least turn the memory back to a struct instance and then compare.

Comment: Fixed; should be same outcome. I thought about that and while the observed instance would be immutable via its exposed interface (and its deserialised form), my interpretation is that the memory representation of a type *is* an observable property. From a generialised serialisation point-of-view I could check the memory representation, form a hash value and use this for comparison; after which uninitialised types would be different to intialised one, thus not being immutable. I think this is a valid use case.

Comment: You have a point, it is a possible use case. So if we want to make such a type immutable from the perspective of serialization and the marshaling mechanism, I guess we'd need to explicitly exclude the hidden mutable fields from the serialization, or provide custom serialization logic that fully initializes the instance first. (But this means we can still make it behave as immutable, with respect to marshaling.)

Comment: I'm not saying its a good use case; just that as a worst case (I like thinking in terms of worst case) the memory of a c# struct is an observable property of a type. Anther example might be crossing a domain. In that case you need to describe the memory layout. The implementation on either side might be different. and on and on...

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of specifying a type to be immutable is to establish the following invariant:

- If two instances of an immutable type are ever observed to be equal, any publicly-observable reference to one may be replaced with a reference to the other without affecting the behavior of either.

Because .NET provides the ability to compare any two references for equality, it's not possible to achieve perfect equivalence among immutable instances.  Nonetheless, the above invariant is still very useful if one regards reference-equality checks as being outside the realm of things for which a class object is responsible.

Note that under this rule, a subclass may define fields beyond those included in an immutable base class, but must not expose them in such a fashion as to violate the above invariant.  Further, a class may include mutable fields provided that they never change in any way that affects a class's visible state.  Consider something like the `hash` field in Java's `string` class.  If it's non-zero, the `hashCode` value of the string is equal to the value stored in the field.  If it's zero, the `hashCode` value of the string is the result of performing certain calculations on the immutable character sequence encapsulated by the string.  Storing the result of the aforementioned calculations into the `hash` field won't affect the hash code of the string; it will merely speed up repeated requests for the value.